# Select all elements of group with group's min value

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the form

```
 Tuple<dynamic, dynamic> pair = new Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>() = 
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.6, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.0, Date = 2/1/2016 , Vol = 0 })}  
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.6, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.464743364189122 })}
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.464743364189122 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 })}
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 })}
  ......
  ......
```

I want to select the pair with minimal abstract of `Vol`(min|Vol1 - Vol2|) everyday after '2/3/2016'(The previous date can be default anything )
The expected form as follow:

```
  {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 }), Volspread = XXXX}
  {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 }), Volspread = XXXX}
  ....... 
  .......
```

Here `Volspread` is just the min abs respectively.

Comment: Do you *have* to use `Tuple` and `dynamic` here? Making the whole thing more semantically-meaningful would make your code easier to follow, if nothing else...

Comment: @Jon Skeet   Maybe you can ignore the first part of code, just regard as a List(but the `Tuple` have to exist)

Comment: Rather than ignoring it, it would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] - and tell us what you're trying to achieve. (It's not clear how the code you've shown is relevant to the description later.)

Comment: Any reason why there are 2 expecteds?

Comment: @ kurakura88 Sorry I forgot the apostrophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting the items with the `min` difference in each group:

```
var result = pairs
    .Where(pair => pair.Item1.Date > new DateTime(2016, 2, 3))
    .Select(pair => new { Item = pair, Diff = Math.Abs(pair.Item1.Vol - pair.Item2.Vol) })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Item.Item1.Date)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Where(item => item.Diff.Equals(group.Min(i => i.Diff))).Select(item => item.Item))
    .ToList();
```

And the testing data:

```
List<Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>> pairs = new List<Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>
{
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.0, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,1), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.6, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,1), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.0, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,1), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.0, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.6, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,1), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.0, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.1, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.1, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.1, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.1, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,2), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 1.4, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,3), Vol = 0 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.7, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.8, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.218217890235992 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.7, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.7, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.464743364189122 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.8, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.218217890235992 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 2.7, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,4), Vol = 0.464743364189122 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.8, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.169725025739105 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.8, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.301649178342484 }),
 new Tuple<dynamic,dynamic>( new { Symbol = "b", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.169725025739105 }, new { Symbol = "c", Close = 1.2, Date = new DateTime(2016,2,5), Vol = 0.301649178342484 }),
};
```

---

Before edit:

You can do this:

```
//Remove irrelevant records and calculate diff
var result = pairs
    .Where(item => item.Item1.Date > new DateTime(2016, 2, 3))
    .Select(item => new { Item = item, Diff = Math.Abs(item.Item1.Vol - item.Item2.Vol) });

//Find min diff
var minDiff = result.Min(item => item.Diff);

//Get only records with min diff
result = result.Where(item => item.Diff.Equals(minDiff)).ToList();
```

Another option is to use the nuget library of `MoreLinq` for `MinBy`

Comment: sorry I mean the min for every day, your code is just the minimal for the whole day?

Comment: @user6703592 - If you want only one item from each group then replace the `SelectMant` with `Select` and the `group.Where` with `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @ Gilad Green Thanks!

Comment: Sure! One thing I don't understand that Why we can't replace `Selectmany` by `Select` only?

Comment: @user6703592 - You can but then you won't have a `IEnumerable<YourType>` but ` `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<YourType>` - Just doesn't look like what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) which has [MinBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs). That does exactly what you need:

```
allPairs.GroupBy( x => x.first.Date.Date ).Select( x => x.MinBy( y => Math.Abs( y.first.Vol - y.second.Vol ) ) );
```

no warranty for syntax errors ;-)